# SSL Certificate 'Not Secure' Issue on localhost with Chrome

Tags: ssl, localhost, wamp, self-signed-certificate

I've set up a self-signed SSL certificate for localhost and imported it into chrome. Despite enabling 'Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost,' I'm still seeing a 'Not Secure' warning. Has anyone encountered and resolved a similar issue with chrome or microsoft edge for local development? Any insights or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Wamp server configurations

```
httpd-ssl.conf;
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
```

```
httpd.conf;
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```